# How can I add switch application functionality?

Tags: blackberry, menuitem

How can I add a Switch application menu item on a Screen?

Comment: Michael i placed the super statement in the MakeMenu method and the switch application menu option does not appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set the DEFAULT_MENU style flag at instantiation. For example:

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Screen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.FullScreen;
...
    Screen myScreen = new FullScreen(Screen.DEFAULT_CLOSE | Screen.DEFAULT_MENU);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this question was asked before on the [Blackberry support forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/add-quot-switch-application-quot-menu-item-into-my-application/m-p/42606).  From what I read it looks like you can create your own but that specific 'switch application' menu item is not a part of their public api.

Quoting RexDoug

> You can still code this yourself by asking the system for running application handles, then creating a PopupScreen that holds the application icons in a single scrolling row (like the system ribbon). You would then launch the applicaiton that corresponds to the icon that the user selected.
>
> See the API docs for ApplicationManager.getVisibleApplications() and ApplicationManager.runApplication().
>
> We did this in just a few classes: RibbonIcon, RibbonIconField, and RibbonPopup. RibbonIconField is just a Horizontal Field Manager added to the popup screen, while RibbonIcon is just a BitmapField subclass that is clickable.

Hope this helps.
-Glen